# XSL - how to insert number characters in text inside <sub></sub>

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got a raw text inside `formula` node, for example:

```
<formula>H2SO4</formula>
```

and my question is, how to match number characters in text and transform the string like this `H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>`

Is it possible via xsl transformation? Thanks much!

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I'm using standard OS X xsltproc command, but maybe I could install SAXON, which supports XSLT 2.0, it may not be a problem.

Comment: This would be quite easy using regex - which requires XSLT 2.0.

Comment: OK, but how? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="formula">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\d+">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <sub>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </sub>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Good for you. I am curious how you got Saxon to work in macOS terminal. Or did you use something else?